# Trash will not empty

Tags: macos, trash

Any tips on forcing the laggards in my trash folder to disappear would be greatly appreciated.
So far no terminal commands or disabling SIP have been successful - any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said *what* Terminal commands you've tried, but don't forget that Trash can exist on other volumes besides the one in your home folder. Run this to remove all Trash.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash /Volumes/*/.Trashes
```

<sup>Be very careful when entering this command</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to grgarside's answer I thought I'd list the various things users can try when being faced with a stubborn Trash can.

**Keyboard shortcuts**

Two keyboard shortcut options that can help are:

- holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while emptying the trash
- do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click (or a right-click) on the actual items within the trash and selecting Delete Immediately...

**Terminal commands**

In addition to the command offered by grgarside, there are other Terminal options you can try:

--Option 1--

This option is best for Yosemite, El Capitan and Sierra.

- Launch Terminal
- Enter the following command `sudo rm -R` in terminal **without** pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> afterwards (note there also has to be a space after the 'R').
- Open the Trash can and drag all the files onto your Terminal window
- Now press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Enter your admin password (note the cursor will not move as you do this, and you won't see any characters appear on the screen)
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd> again

--Option 2--

This option is for users of macOS prior to Yosemite, El Capitan or Sierra

- Launch Terminal
- Enter the `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` command
- Now press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Enter your admin password (note the cursor will not move as you do this, and you won't see any characters appear on the screen)
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd> again